# clicking on AppCenter tab opens up a blank page

Tags: marketing-cloud, app-development

I created new account in exacttarget, logged in and clicking on AppCenter opens up a blank page. Any help, would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean you created a new account on code.exacttarget.com and then registered as a developer in App Center...then when you click on the "App Center" menu link, you are taken to a blank page?